# APL: How do you remove rows and columns that contain ONLY 0s from a matrix?

Tags: matrix, binary, apl

In the matrix

```
0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

I'd like to reshape it by peeling off the 4th column and 4th row into

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

What is the smart way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a matrix such as:

```
A←0 1 1 0 1⍀1 0 0 1 1\3 3⍴⍳9
```

Which is:

```
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 2 3
4 0 0 5 6
0 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 8 9
```

Empty rows and columns can be removed with:

```
(0∨.≠B)/B←(A∨.≠0)⌿A
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

**Trim only the outsides:**

Trim leading and trailing columns:

```
(∨\0∨.≠B)/B←(⌽∨\⌽0∨.≠A)/A
```

Trim leading and trailing rows:

```
(-2↑+/^\⌽B^.=0)↓B←(∨\A∨.≠0)⌿A
```

All together:

```
(-2↑+/^\⌽D^.=0)↓D←(∨\C∨.≠0)⌿C←(∨\0∨.≠B)/B←(⌽∨\⌽0∨.≠A)/A
```

Comment: Would there be a way to improve this into removing only outer rows and columns of 0s? For example if there was a 3 x 3 matrix of 1s with a middle row of 0s, it would not remove this row?

Comment: Define a "reduction vector" as a separate var (for readability) and then do a (∧\var)∨⌽∧\var on it to only remove consecutive segments at start or end.

Comment: What do you mean by a reduction vector? And by "it" do you mean the matrix?